# Car Rental Business model

Tags: f#

I am in new to F#, so please have mercy. Trying to model a Car Rental business in F#. My types are:

- Customer
- Driver
- Car
- VehicleType
- RentalAgreement **NOT IMPLEMENTED YET**

My specific question is can an F# class have a member that is a Discriminated Union? A car should have an attribute that reflects what type of vehicle it is...Compact, Sedan, Truck, etc... Below is my code so far...

```
namespace DSL2

// a DU
type vehicleType =  Truck | Compact | Econ | Sedan

// a record
type Customer =  {firstName: string; lastName: string; gender: string}

//a class implicit ctor'tion
type Car(numdoors:int ,  make: string , year:int)  = class
    member this.NumDoors = numdoors
    member this.Make = make
    member this.Year = year  
end

//a class explicit ctor'tion
type Car2 = class
    val NumDoors: int
    val Make: string
    val Year: int

    (*first ctor*)
    new (numDoors, make, year) = 
        {NumDoors = numDoors; Make = make; Year = year}
        
 end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just add the member to the class and include it in the constructor with the desired value.

```
// a DU
type vehicleType =  Truck | Compact | Econ | Sedan

// a record
type Customer =  {firstName: string; lastName: string; gender: string}

//a class implicit ctor'tion
type Car(numdoors:int ,  make: string , year:int)  = class
    member this.NumDoors = numdoors
    member this.Make = make
    member this.Year = year  
end

//a class explicit ctor'tion
type Car2 = class
    val NumDoors: int
    val Make: string
    val Year: int
    val DU: vehicleType

    (*first ctor*)
    new (numDoors, make, year, cust) = 
        {NumDoors = numDoors; Make = make; Year = year;  DU = Truck }
 end
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a discriminated union is just like any other type and can be used as the type of any field, property, constructor parameter etc.

Just add a parameter of type `vehicleType` to the `Car` constructor:

```
type Car(numdoors:int, make: string, year:int, vehicleType : vehicleType) = class
    member this.NumDoors = numdoors
    member this.Make = make
    member this.Year = year
    member this.VehicleType = vehicleType
end
```

Note that it's bad F# style to name types with initial lower-case letters, so I'd suggest renaming it to `VehicleType`.